# Can not push docker container to Amazon ecr

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I've made an image

```
111111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/edx-cluster
```

I trying to push it to Amazon, but always I received the same error. But I can push it to Docker hub without any errors

```
docker push 111111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/edx-cluster:latest
The push refers to repository [111111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/edx-cluster]
ae0062a2d077: Preparing 
c52921d94e3e: Preparing 
aa5d8376b8c4: Preparing 
79a57fc7fbcc: Preparing 
8a1159c97df8: Preparing 
adb2c7b88404: Waiting 
d3a701e27209: Waiting 
d8d26a0d0d6c: Waiting 
a34d1923f571: Waiting 
9fd1fd063a37: Waiting 
397415b17275: Waiting 
25bb34378fc3: Waiting 
711cc8b6546f: Waiting 
8d733d8c32ff: Waiting 
69ce838fa634: Waiting 
e252a759abc0: Waiting 
26b126eb8632: Waiting 
220d34b5f6c9: Waiting 
8a5132998025: Waiting 
aca233ed29c3: Waiting 
e5d2f035d7a4: Waiting 
unauthorized: authentication required
```

But I have in dokcer config file auth block with my AWS ecr link and auth key, that was generated after I have called `aws ecr get-login`
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to get login by

```
aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region <region>
```

you will get a docker login copy that command and execute

```
docker login -u AWS -p 'long key' https://xxx.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com
```

you will get and output of

> Login Succeeded

Comment: So I got new key but after `docker push` I got the same error

Comment: damn, you get Login Succeeded msg?

Comment: I got this `docker login -u AWS -p 'long key' https://111111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`